# How reduce size of PPT 2010 Notes Pages PDFs?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PPT presentation of about 400 slides that I periodically update and publish as PDF.  The view I publish is the Notes Pages.  This worked fine for several years, during which time I was using PPT 2002.  I recently upgraded to PPT 2010, and now I find that the PDFs I create are about 25 times bigger than they used to be, and the text in the slides part of the Notes Pages is now neither selectable nor searchable in Acrobat.

According to [Why does Powerpoint 2010 print notes pages to PDF as raster images?](https://superuser.com/questions/568688/why-does-powerpoint-2010-print-notes-pages-to-pdf-as-raster-images) , the problem is that PPT 2010 is rendering the slides' content as images, which is not what earlier versions of PPT did.  The solution offered in that discussion involves Office Automation and VBA, neither of which I know anything about, and it's not clear whether that approach solves the problem of the text in the slides not being selectable or searchable in the PDF.

Isn't there a simple way to get PPT 2010 to print Notes Pages to PDF the way it did in PPT 2002?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question at the [Microsoft Community site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/how-reduce-size-of-ppt-2010-notes-pages-pdfs/c8929ec1-0a97-4d70-8b27-de63bb5d8cfe), where [Steve Rindsberg](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/8710e173-7c59-402b-a734-2916ae7fd288) posted a VBA-based solution that works well enough for me, though how well it works for slides with images on them is unclear. (Steve and I got different results in that case.)